# Pyspark: how to apply pandas_udf?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to apply `pandas_udf` in `pyspark`.

I have a pyspark dataframe like the following:

```
+-------------------+------------------+--------+-------+
|                lat|               lon|duration|stop_id|
+-------------------+------------------+--------+-------+
|  -6.23748779296875| 106.6937255859375|     247|      0|
|  -6.23748779296875| 106.6937255859375|    2206|      1|
|  -6.23748779296875| 106.6937255859375|     609|      2|
| 0.5733972787857056|101.45503234863281|   16879|      3|
| 0.5733972787857056|101.45503234863281|    4680|      4|
| -6.851855278015137|108.64261627197266|     164|      5|
| -6.851855278015137|108.64261627197266|     220|      6|
| -6.851855278015137|108.64261627197266|    1669|      7|
|-0.9033176600933075|100.41548919677734|   30811|      8|
|-0.9033176600933075|100.41548919677734|   23404|      9|
+-------------------+------------------+--------+-------+
```

I am trying a simple function to create a column `test` that is `1` if duration is greater than `1000` and `0` otherwise.

```
schema =StructType([
  StructField('test', IntegerType(), True),
  StructField('stop_id', IntegerType(), True)
])
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def probTime(stop_df):
    stopid = stop_df['stop_id'].values[0]
    val = stop_df['duration'].values[0]
    test = 0
    if val > 1000:
      test = 1
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['prob_time'] = test
    df['stop_id'] = stopid
    return df
```

but I get an empty table.

```
sp = stop_df.groupBy("stop_id").apply(probTime)
sp.show(5)

+----+-------+
|test|stop_id|
+----+-------+
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises with the assignment of the new DF inside the grouping function: you need to assign the values as lists. Take for instance the following examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
test = 1
stopid = 1
df['prob_time'] = test
df['stop_id'] = stopid
print(df)
```

This yields:

```
Columns: [prob_time, stop_id]
Index: []
```

compared to

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
test = 1
stopid = 1
df['prob_time'] = [test]
df['stop_id'] = [stopid]
print(df)
```

which yields

```
   prob_time  stop_id
0          1        1
```

Therefore you should change your code to the latter form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a function, it could be done directly on spark using 'when' function.

1) import when function

`from pyspark.sql.functions import when`

2) Use it to create a new column in existing dataframe

`stop_df = stop_df.withColumn('test', when(stop_df['duration']>1000, 1).otherwise(0))`

stop_df dataframe will have the test column with required values

Comment: I would need to understand the function because I need to write a more complex function